# Perl processes disappears after some days

Tags: perl, centos, rhel

I have a perl file (**test.pl**).

It will work in recurring manner.
The purpose of the file is send emails from DB

Following is the code in test.pl

```
sub send_mail{

$db->connect();

# Some DB operations #
# Send mail #

$db->disconnect();
sleep(5);

send_mail();

}

send_mail();
```

Iam executing 5 instance of this file ,like as below

```
perl test.pl  >> /var/www/html/emailerrorlog/error1.log 2>&1 &
perl test.pl  >> /var/www/html/emailerrorlog/error2.log 2>&1 &
perl test.pl  >> /var/www/html/emailerrorlog/error3.log 2>&1 &
perl test.pl  >> /var/www/html/emailerrorlog/error4.log 2>&1 &
perl test.pl  >> /var/www/html/emailerrorlog/error5.log 2>&1 &
```

if i execute the command  `ps -ef | grep perl | grep -v grep`

I can see  5 instances of above mentioned perl file

That file  will work perfectly for some days

But after some days, the perl processes  will start  to disappear one by one .

After some days all process will disappear.
Now. if i execute the command ps -ef | grep perl | grep -v grep ,I can't see any process,

I can't  see any error log  in the log files.

So, what may be the chances for disappearing the perl processes?

How can i debugg it ?

Where can i see the perl error log?

It has the same issue in Centos and Red Hat Linux

Any one have idea?

Comment: Did you check /var/log/messages?

Comment: @sunil_milec i don't getting the particular folder through terminal.
cd /var/log/messages

Comment: /var/log is a folder and messages is a file.

Comment: @sunil_mlec Ok.Thanks for the reply.I think " Fabricio"'s answer will be the correct one according to my situation

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure if that is the problem but it would probably help if you avoid recursion in a permanently executing process... That slowly increases the stack use and will eventually kill the process when the stack size limit is reached.

try something like this instead:

```
sub send_mail{

   $db->connect();

   # Some DB operations #
   # Send mail #

   $db->disconnect();

}

while (1) {
   send_mail();
   sleep(5);
}
```

Comment: Thanks  for the reply.But what is the difference if we use like this 
while (1) {
   send_mail();
   sleep(5);
}

Comment: I think you should learn what recursion is and what its implications are before using it. In short if you call a `sub a()` from inside `a()` this is recursion and, in your case since you keep calling it forever, stack memory usage will increase until the process breaks. More on this subject [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion_%28computer_science%29).

Comment: The difference is, in your implementation, you are not giving the code a chance to come out of recursion.  So, that way, you code keeps on adding references to system stack and after some days, the stack becomes full thereby killing the process.

Comment: The `while (1)` will make sure it runs forever.

Comment: @Linto In the previous link I sent (on recursion) you have interest to read the section [Stack space](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion_%28computer_science%29#Stack_space)

Comment: @Fabricio, Thank you very much .I also think that may be the issue.I will change my code like you said.And let me start to execute it for some days.and confirm it.Thanks one more time

Comment: @Fabricio.Let me know one more thing.I am outputting some result like "Finished Step1" , "Finished step2"....Will it be a problem  as the file is running forever?

Comment: @linto The only thing is your log file will grow but that's unlikely to fill up your file system to a point of rupture. BTW, out of curiosity the suspected problem is called a **stack overflow**, rings a bell doesn't it?  ;-)